# How to convert a UIColor to UInt32 ? I get the error Ambiguous use of operator "+="

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to convert this objective-code to swift:

> Objective-C Version

```
+ (NSNumber *)serializeColor:(UIColor *)color
{

    uint32_t integer = 0;
    CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
    [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    integer += ((int)(alpha * 255) & 0xff) << 24;
    integer += ((int)(red * 255) & 0xff) << 16;
    integer += ((int)(green * 255) & 0xff) << 8;
    integer += ((int)(blue * 255) & 0xff);
    return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:integer];
}
```

But then I keep getting the error in the question:

> Swift Version

```
class func serialize(color: UIColor) {
    var integer: UInt32 = 0;
    var red: CGFloat, green:CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat
    color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

    integer += (Int((alpha * 255) & 0xff)
    integer += (Int((red * 255)) & 0xff) << 16
    integer += (Int((green * 255)) & 0xff) << 8
    integer += (Int((blue * 255)) & 0xff)
```

Comment: you need to initialize your vars red, green, blue and alpha before passing them to getRed method `var r: CGFloat = 0, g:CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0`. Integer is UInt32 type so you need to coerce all the CGFloats to UInt32 before adding it up to integer

Comment: You forgot to specify your method return type NSNumber or just UInt32

Comment: Hey Leo, thanks for a reply! It works! And I did forget to return the return type, my fault.

Comment: You are welcome. I have posted an example of how you can extend UIColor to extra the hex value from any color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize your vars red, green, blue and alpha before passing them to getRed method. Integer is UInt32 type so you need to coerce all the CGFloats to UInt32 before adding it up to integer or make it an Int. I would do it as follow:

```
extension UIColor  {
    var hexa: Int {
        var red: CGFloat = 0, green: CGFloat = 0, blue: CGFloat = 0, alpha: CGFloat = 0
        getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
        return Int(alpha * 255) << 24
             + Int(red   * 255) << 16
             + Int(green * 255) << 8
             + Int(blue  * 255)
    }
}
```

---

The other way:

```
extension UIColor{
    convenience init(hexa: Int) {
        self.init(red:   CGFloat((hexa & 0xFF0000)   >> 16)/255,
                  green: CGFloat((hexa & 0xFF00)     >> 8 )/255,
                  blue:  CGFloat((hexa & 0xFF)            )/255,
                  alpha: CGFloat((hexa & 0xFF000000) >> 24)/255)
    }
}
```

---

Testing

```
UIColor(hexa: UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.23).hexa)   // r 1,0 g 0,0 b 0,0 a 0,227
```

Note: I think you should use UInt32 as you had in your original code to make sure it works also with old 32-bit devices.

```
extension UIColor {
    var hexa: UInt32 {
        var red: CGFloat = 0, green: CGFloat = 0, blue: CGFloat = 0, alpha: CGFloat = 0
        getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
        var value: UInt32 = 0
        value += UInt32(alpha * 255) << 24
        value += UInt32(red   * 255) << 16
        value += UInt32(green * 255) << 8
        value += UInt32(blue  * 255)
        return value
    }
    convenience init(hexa: UInt32) {
        self.init(red  : CGFloat((hexa & 0xFF0000)   >> 16) / 255,
                  green: CGFloat((hexa & 0xFF00)     >> 8)  / 255,
                  blue : CGFloat( hexa & 0xFF)              / 255,
                  alpha: CGFloat((hexa & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is nonsense because of the unbalanced parentheses:

```
integer += (Int((alpha * 255) & 0xff)
```

And you forgot the `<< 24`. And anyway, what are all those extra parentheses doing in your code? You can express this more simply without them:

```
func serialize(color: UIColor) -> Int {
    var integer = 0
    var (red,green,blue,alpha) = (0,0,0,0) as (CGFloat,CGFloat,CGFloat,CGFloat)
    color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

    integer += (Int(alpha * 255) & 0xff) << 24
    integer += (Int(red * 255) & 0xff) << 16
    integer += (Int(green * 255) & 0xff) << 8
    integer += (Int(blue * 255) & 0xff)
    return integer
}
```

(I am unclear whether a UIInt32 is really needed here, but if it is, then return a UIInt32 and coerce as you return `integer`.)